# Why is the following code not printing the linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} node;

void add(node **head, node **tail, int data) {
    node *temp1, *temp2;
    temp1 = (node*) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp1;
        *tail = temp1;
    } else {
        for (temp2 = *head; temp2->next != NULL; temp2 = temp2->next)
            temp2->next = temp1;
        *tail = temp1;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *temp, *head, *tail;
    head = NULL;
    add(&head, &tail, 1);
    add(&head, &tail, 2);
    add(&head, &tail, 3);
    add(&head, &tail, 4);

    for (temp = head; temp != (node *) 0; temp = temp->next) {
        printf("[%d]->", (temp->next));
    }
    printf("[NULL]\n\n");
}
```

What is the error and why is it not printing?
What is the error and why is it printing only [0]->NULL? I tried various forms but I am unable to do so. What is the problem?
Is there a problem with the pointers? Or is enough memory not allocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a statement in the for cycle:

```
for(temp2=*head; temp2->next!=NULL; temp2=temp2->next)
temp2->next=temp1;
*tail=temp1;
```

this will be executed as

```
for(temp2=*head; temp2->next!=NULL; temp2=temp2->next) {
    temp2->next=temp1;
}
*tail=temp1;
```

You can fix it just adding an empty block to for (`{}`) or `;`

```
for(temp2=*head; temp2->next!=NULL; temp2=temp2->next) {}
temp2->next=temp1;
*tail=temp1;
```

Also probably what you want in your `printf` statement is

```
printf("[%d]->",(temp->data));
```

Comment: note: prefer `{}`. the semicolon `;` is easily overlooked.

Comment: Wow...thank you @Salem.. I had wasted more than 1 day on this small error..thanks again :-)

Comment: i still think your for loop is redundant to just using (*tail)->next instead of temp2->next...

Comment: @xmoex You are right, I didn't noticed that he was using a tail pointer also. Just add what was the original error in your answer and I think it will be a better answer to the problem

Answer (score 2):

I my opinion you don't have to utilize a for loop. If I understand you correctly you want to add an element to the end of the list. So just do it like this:

```
// if list is empty ...
if (*head == NULL) {
    // ... insert new node
    *head = temp1;
    *tail = temp1;
}
// ... otherwise ...
else {
    // ... insert new node at tail ...
    (*tail)->next = temp1;
    // ... then move tail to new node
    *tail = temp1;
}
```

It works because you don't have to find the end of the list, you already know where it is: it's `*tail`! So you just add you element to `tail`'s next pointer, and the you move the `tail`-pointer itself...

**Output is:**

```
[1]->[2]->[3]->[4]->[NULL]
```

And as Salem pointed out you should fix your `printf`:

```
printf("[%d]->", (temp->data));
```